# Param is missing or the value is empty ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good Day, i am trying to update the rating of a user using form_for to populate the text_field of its current rating and then update it to user entered value. So far, its seems all simple but something doesn't seem well and i am getting this error. Help will be highly appreciated!

user controller:

```
def edit_rating
      @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
      @user = User.find(@ad.user_id)

      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:notice] = "User Updated Successfully"
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
      else
      end
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:firstName, :lastName, :email , :password , :location, :rating)
    end
```

edit_rating view:

```
<h2>
    Edit User Rating
</h2>

<h4>
    Name: <%= @user.firstName %>
</h4>

<p>
    Current Rating: <%= @user.rating%>
</p>

<%=form_for(:user , :url => {:action => 'edit_rating' , :id => @user.id}) do |f| %>

    <p>
        Updated Rating: <%= f.text_field(:rating) %>
    </p>

    <%= submit_tag("Update Rating") %>
<% end%>
```

This is the error that i am getting.

[image]

Comment: You're saying you require firstName,LastName,email,password, location and rating but you're only passing an id

Comment: Is this occurring on a POST or GET request? Does this happen when you submit the form or just view the form? The Parameters in the screen shot show that there are no params for the `:user`, hence the error message. You need two different controller actions for a form: One to view the form (an HTTP GET), and the other to process the form (an HTTP POST).

Comment: As of now, it is on viewing the form.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, that was some amazing piece of advice! Actually helped me in identifying where i was going wrong and how to actually solve the problem! Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the reverse not to permit you can only use the params you only want to use:

```
@user.update_attributes(rating: params[:user][:rating])
```

Comment: It gives "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" on the update_attributes line.

Comment: that mean user paramter is not sending to server, can you check the logs and make sure from the paramter sending, if that is the case then your code should work when you make sure attributes send correctly

Comment: ohh, i can already see that only id paramter send from the error screenshoot, then the attributes is not send to server to update user

Comment: I am actually sending parameter from index page to edit page and then identifying the ad using its id from the table and then finding out which user has actually posted the ad. The user who posted the ad is successfully found in the @user = User.find(@ad.user_id) 
i actually outputted its values on the edit page and they are showing all fine.

Comment: Yes, id is pass correctly but no other params as rating

Comment: Solved the issue! Thanks a lot @mohamed-ibrahim!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76554/discussion-between-ali-abbas-jaffri-and-mohamed-ibrahim).